# Duplicate data in a unique indexed field in mysql

Tags: mysql, import, unique-constraint

I have a table with 3 fields :

Id : int - primery key.

u_tid : int -  index(unique).

u_name: text

I had near 13 milion records in a table. I imported a sql file containing 17 milion records (with some duplicate data regarding existing records in the table) into that table. 
The imported sql file uses  "insert ignore into" for inserting rows. Import finished successfully, but after importing, I found more than 1 milion duplicate data in u_tid field in the table.
How is it possible? Is it a bug in mysql? Or I have done somthing wrong?

Screenshot in PMA :
[screenshot 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ooSZE.jpg)

Screenshot for " ... where un_tid+0=110769551" in mysql cli:
[screenshot 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fO5cC.jpg)

Version : 5.5.46 on Ubuntu 14.04.2

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `member_name` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `un_tid` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `un_name` varchar(150) COLLATE utf8_persian_ci NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `un_tid` (`un_tid`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_persian_ci;
```

Comment: It is only possible if you do not have a unique index on `u_tid` field. Can you pls post the create table statement for your table?

Comment: @Shadow
  I Added create table statment to question

Comment: This looks like phpmyadmin, in which case, your first assumption should be that you need to verify this result with another tool, like the `mysql` CLI, to rule out a bug in PMA.  Or, `SELECT * FROM member_name WHERE un_tid + 0 = 110769551;`.  The `+ 0` is significant to prove a point, so, don't omit it.  Do you get multiple rows?  What MySQL Server version (`SELECT @@VERSION;`) are you running?

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot Mysql version and screenshot of the query that you suggested is added to question. thanks

Comment: I can't reproduce the behaviour, I get the duplicate error as expected: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/9eecb7d

Comment: If I change the 2nd insert to ignore, I get 1 record only, see http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/69e57/6

Comment: @Shadow so what is happened to my table? how is it possible? it could be said that it is a bug that occurs in large number of records?

Comment: You need to be able to reproduce the incorrect behaviour to mark it as a bug. If you succeed in doing this, you need to report it to mysql. However, I would not be surprised if it turned out that sg else contributes to this behaviour.